# Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.BufferedStream'

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am having an issue with Windows 8 apps and obtaining a steam from the opened file. There are other ways to approach reading/writing a file in Windows 8, but for the sake of being able to pull out a standard stream I am trying to see if I can. So far no good. The issue is that System.IO.BufferedStream is not part of System.IO in Windows 8 apps. Thus the following code:

```
    (MemoryStream)(await (await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("SOMEFILE")).OpenStreamForWriteAsync());
```

My apologies for the condensed code. The above code throws the mentioned exception. The issue, once again, is I cannot create a buffered stream. I was wondering if there was some way around this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rather than apologizing for the condensed code, why not just provide *less* condensed code (just putting it into two lines would help a lot).

Comment: Streams created by WinRT are already buffered by the operating system.  Don't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code i use for Reading/Writing a file in Windows 8. It works and i hope it helps you too.

```
    // Read from a file line by line
    public async Task ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // get the file
            StorageFile myStorageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("MyDocument.txt");
            var readThis = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(myStorageFile);
            foreach (var line in readThis)
            {
                String myStringLine = line;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("File read successfully.");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException)
        {              
        }
    }
    // Write to a file line by line
    public async void SaveFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // set storage file
            StorageFile myStorageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyDocument.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            List<String> myDataLineList = new List<string>();
            await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(myStorageFile, myDataLineList);
            Debug.WriteLine("File saved successfully.");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException)
        {              
        }
    }
```

Comment: There was a time when you could of just used their static file class without any of the async stuff or their lovely new folder structure approach. Async is amazing, but they are caking it a little too much and killing simpler alternatives.

Comment: To be honest i have spent 2 days searching for an example to read/write from/to a file. With StreamReader, StreamWriter this used to be a simple task. But now i think using async is the way to go. If others have another method, easier to read/write a file i hope they will share their code here. Also keep in mind a "metro" app has 3 folders: Local, Roaming and Temp. You should use those. I think from a custom folder you can only read data, when you try to write data you will get "fileaccessdenied". Here is a link: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Comment: I'm not going to argue that there is a huge issue with Async. Provided the complexity of today's applications we need Async. Just when it comes to things like this its very frustrating because things that used to take 2 minutes to write out now take far more consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes - you're casting to `MemoryStream`, and it's *not* a `MemoryStream`. `System.IO.BufferedStream` appears to *exist* - it's just not *public*; it's an implementation detail which you shouldn't need to worry about. You can't cast it to a `MemoryStream` though, because it's not one.

It's not clear why you're casting to `MemoryStream` at all, but you should be able to just use `Stream` instead. If you *need* a `MemoryStream`, you'll have to create one yourself and copy the data into it.

Comment: Its a habit, I am used to buffering stuff into a memory stream; here it does not really apply provided I'm reading from a file. Its 4 in the morning.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov: Well, I suggest you get out of the habit then :) If you're only reading it once, it doesn't matter anyway - and even in other cases I'd trust the OS to do the right thing in general. Note that even in non-WinRT situations, you can't just cast any arbitrary stream to MemoryStream.

Comment: Right, because its not pointing to a location in memory but a socket or a file. This makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should be able to just use the returned `Stream`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx

Is there a reason to cast it to a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: I just changed it to a stream rather than a MemoryStream. I usually use MemoryStreams to ensure that i know that the stream is in the memory. I guess I can see why this is not correct when reading a file.

Comment: And its an ugly habit to assume all streams are equal.